# Error while installing Shockwave on Ubuntu: "End-of-central-directory signature not found."

Tags: software-installation, windows, software-center, downloads

I have a computer with Ubuntu already installed. I tried to install Shockwave, but I received this error:

```
Archive:  /home/singh/Downloads/Shockwave_Installer_Full.exe
[/home/singh/Downloads/Shockwave_Installer_Full.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/singh/Downloads/Shockwave_Installer_Full.exe or /home/singh/Downloads/Shockwave_Installer_Full.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/singh/Downloads/Shockwave_Installer_Full.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Am I able to install Shockwave on Ubuntu or do I need to install Windows to have Shockwave?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a .swf viewer on Ubuntu you should install and use Gnash.   It's available in the repositories.

If you want Windows installed on the computer you will first have to go and buy a copy. (You already have a better operating system for free however).  Some Windows programs will run OK under Ubuntu but you will need to install Wine to do so.

Anything that ends in exe is probably a Windows file.  If you want to find programs to install use the Ubuntu Software Centre.  I'd recommend that you investigate the software centre first before you give up on Ubuntu.

Also have a read of [Linux is not Windows](http://linux.oneandoneis2.org/LNW.htm).